# Counting values with condition in one DataFrame and adding the result to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, conditional-statements

I have two `DataFrames`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4],
                  "text": ["a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b"]})
```

Output `df1`:

```
   id
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

Output `df2`:

```
   id value
0   1    a
1   1    a
2   2    b
3   4    a
4   4    b
5   4    b
```

My goal is to add three columns in `df1`.

In `count_all` I would like to count the corresponding ids in df2. E.g. id 4 exists 3 times in df2.

In `count_a` I would like to count the corresponding ids in df2 where the text value == a.

In `count_b` I would like to count the corresponding ids in df2 where the text value == b.

```
   id  count_all  count_a  count_b
0   1          2        2        0
1   2          1        0        1
2   3          0        0        0
3   4          3        1        2
```

How can this be done with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `margins` parameter, add missing index values or change columns ordering by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last join to `df1` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = (df1.join(pd.crosstab(df2['id'], df2['text'], margins=True)
                 .reindex(index=df1['id'].unique(), 
                          columns=['All'] + df2['text'].unique().tolist(), 
                          fill_value=0)
                 .add_prefix('count_'), on='id'))
print (df)
   id  count_All  count_a  count_b
0   1          2        2        0
1   2          1        0        1
2   3          0        0        0
3   4          3        1        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
df1.join(df2.groupby('id').agg(
    count_all = ('id','count'),
    count_a=('text',lambda x: sum(x.eq('a'))),
    count_b = ('text',lambda x: sum(x.eq('b')))),on='id').fillna(0)
```